# Fixed or consistent mount location for a USB hard drive

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, usb

I store my music on an external hard drive, and play them with foobar2k. However, the drive letter changes, which usually means I need to rebuild a fairly large playlist every so often.

I'm wondering if there's a way to reserve a drive letter for a specific external device (or type of device) by device ID or volume name, or if I'm better off using a NTFS mount point, and re-mounting the drive to a folder each time.

I'm using either a Windows XP or 7 system, and the external drive is NTFS.

Comment: Have heard of 'reserving drive letters' before but personally i've always used mount points for USB backup drives...

Comment: reserving drive letters feels less hacky to me, assuming it could be done on the other hand I know how to use mountpoints *right now*, so that would be an easier solution. On the gripping hand... What i really should do is find an even hackier convoluted solution than either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Disk Management to assign a letter.  It will stick.  My thumb drive was set to Y and it is always Y.

Right click My Computer and choose manage,  Then in Disk Management: right click the drive and assign it a new letter.  Lower in the alphabet the better,

Comment: that seems to work