# OK to install Flight Simulator on removeable media?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, installation, usb-flash-drive

I have a never used version of 'Flight Simulator X - Deluxe Edition' which I'd like to install on a laptop for my kids.

Problem is the laptop doesn't have that much disk spare and FS requires a nominal 15Gb (the machine has about 20Gb spare but really I don't want it get much less than that because of other stuff I use it for).

Can I install the game to a flash drive mounted on the laptop and then when they want to play the game stick the flash drive in and start the game as normal ?

I can't see why this wouldn't work but just thought I'd check.

If there's something about flash drives which is bad would it be OK with a removeable hard drive over USB 2 ?

The OS is Windows Vista Ultimate 32 bit.

---

**EDIT**: Just for future readers I went ahead and did this and it works fine.

Comment: If you read the FAQ you will see that games are not accepted on this site.

Comment: You could try it, it won't hurt anything.  It'll run slower (flash is fast, USB is not) and it could have issues if the drive letter isn't always the same.   But, I'd try to move other files that are taking up space to an external drive, rather than run programs off the external.

Comment: I disagree - while its for a game, the same things would be applicable for other software

Comment: @Xavierjazz I'm sorry I hadn't realised the games thing although as journeyman geek says it is quite general and not specific to games.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why it wouldn't work, but there's a few things to consider

1. your software is going to freak if things are not on the same drive letter - you may want to make sure the drive you install it on has a fixed drive letter - [see here](https://superuser.com/questions/362133/fixed-or-consistent-mount-location-for-a-usb-hard-drive).
2. USB 2.0 is a fair bit slower than a native interface, performance may suck
3. vista supports [symlinks](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-symlinks-in-windows-vista/)  or you could run [steam mover](http://www.traynier.com/software/steammover) to move files selectively